# Could not find the application build.gradle file under project directory

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, build.gradle

[image]

I want to change the build.gradle (project NameApplication) file, but it is not in my project. What should I do?

Comment: There is a `build.gradle` file in the screenshot provided, first item under `Gradle Scripts` header.

Comment: Sometimes if I fail to locate the project level build.gradle file, it helps to switch from the Android perspective to the Project perspective (dropdown list above file tree  in "Project" panel)

Comment: Well, there must be two build.gradle files
One Project nameProject
One Module app 
But in my project there is not (Project NameProject)

Comment: Make sure you've imported the top level directory when importing a project. If you've selected the `app` directory on import you'll only see the one `build.gradle`

Comment: thank you , Russell Cullen
My problem has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

Its not in my project, even after trying all of the solutions; listed above. the image shows the contents of my folder, all of them.

[image]